# Fail to startup Oracle Database (failure in processing system parameters)

Tags: database, oracle, startup

I'm going to setup Oracle DB 12c on Ubuntu 16.04. I'm following [this guide](https://medium.com/venturenxt/install-oracle-database-12c-on-ubuntu-16-04-c081d51c0f9d).

But when I was trying to STARTUP, it's fail with this error:

```
SQL> connect sys as sysdba
Enter password: 
Connected to an idle instance.
SQL> STARTUP;
ORA-01078: failure in processing system parameters
LRM-00109: could not open parameter file '/u01/app/oracle/product/12.2.0/dbhome_1/dbs/initSID.ora'
SQL>
```

How can I resolve this?

[Update]
I have resolved this by this way:

> cp init.ora ./initSID.ora

Then it STARUP as well. But I still can not access to https://127.0.0.1:5500/em

I updated env as request from @vs_coder:

```
LC_PAPER=vi_VN
XDG_VTNR=7
ORBIT_SOCKETDIR=/tmp/orbit-huynq
XDG_SESSION_ID=c2
LC_ADDRESS=vi_VN
CLUTTER_IM_MODULE=xim
LC_MONETARY=vi_VN
TERMINATOR_UUID=######################
IBUS_DISABLE_SNOOPER=1
XDG_GREETER_DATA_DIR=/var/lib/lightdm-data/huynq
GIO_LAUNCHED_DESKTOP_FILE_PID=4970
SESSION=ubuntu
GPG_AGENT_INFO=/home/huynq/.gnupg/S.gpg-agent:0:1
TERM=xterm
SHELL=/bin/bash
XDG_MENU_PREFIX=gnome-
ORACLE_UNQNAME=DB12C
TMPDIR=/tmp
DERBY_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/db
QT_LINUX_ACCESSIBILITY_ALWAYS_ON=1
LC_NUMERIC=vi_VN
WINDOWID=75497476
OLDPWD=/u01/app/oracle/product/12.2.0/dbhome_1
GNOME_KEYRING_CONTROL=
UPSTART_SESSION=unix:abstract=/com/ubuntu/upstart-session/1000/1478
GTK_MODULES=gail:atk-bridge:unity-gtk-module
USER=oracle
http_proxy=#######################
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/u01/app/oracle/product/12.2.0/dbhome_1/lib:/lib:/usr/lib:/usr/lib64
QT_ACCESSIBILITY=1
LC_TELEPHONE=vi_VN
LS_COLORS=rs=0:di=01;34:ln=01;36:mh=00:pi=40;33:so=01;35:do=01;35:bd=40;33;01:cd=40;33;01:or=40;31;01:mi=00:su=37;41:sg=30;43:ca=30;41:tw=30;42:ow=34;42:st=37;44:ex=01;32:*.tar=01;31:*.tgz=01;31:*.arc=01;31:*.arj=01;31:*.taz=01;31:*.lha=01;31:*.lz4=01;31:*.lzh=01;31:*.lzma=01;31:*.tlz=01;31:*.txz=01;31:*.tzo=01;31:*.t7z=01;31:*.zip=01;31:*.z=01;31:*.Z=01;31:*.dz=01;31:*.gz=01;31:*.lrz=01;31:*.lz=01;31:*.lzo=01;31:*.xz=01;31:*.bz2=01;31:*.bz=01;31:*.tbz=01;31:*.tbz2=01;31:*.tz=01;31:*.deb=01;31:*.rpm=01;31:*.jar=01;31:*.war=01;31:*.ear=01;31:*.sar=01;31:*.rar=01;31:*.alz=01;31:*.ace=01;31:*.zoo=01;31:*.cpio=01;31:*.7z=01;31:*.rz=01;31:*.cab=01;31:*.jpg=01;35:*.jpeg=01;35:*.gif=01;35:*.bmp=01;35:*.pbm=01;35:*.pgm=01;35:*.ppm=01;35:*.tga=01;35:*.xbm=01;35:*.xpm=01;35:*.tif=01;35:*.tiff=01;35:*.png=01;35:*.svg=01;35:*.svgz=01;35:*.mng=01;35:*.pcx=01;35:*.mov=01;35:*.mpg=01;35:*.mpeg=01;35:*.m2v=01;35:*.mkv=01;35:*.webm=01;35:*.ogm=01;35:*.mp4=01;35:*.m4v=01;35:*.mp4v=01;35:*.vob=01;35:*.qt=01;35:*.nuv=01;35:*.wmv=01;35:*.asf=01;35:*.rm=01;35:*.rmvb=01;35:*.flc=01;35:*.avi=01;35:*.fli=01;35:*.flv=01;35:*.gl=01;35:*.dl=01;35:*.xcf=01;35:*.xwd=01;35:*.yuv=01;35:*.cgm=01;35:*.emf=01;35:*.ogv=01;35:*.ogx=01;35:*.aac=00;36:*.au=00;36:*.flac=00;36:*.m4a=00;36:*.mid=00;36:*.midi=00;36:*.mka=00;36:*.mp3=00;36:*.mpc=00;36:*.ogg=00;36:*.ra=00;36:*.wav=00;36:*.oga=00;36:*.opus=00;36:*.spx=00;36:*.xspf=00;36:
ORACLE_SID=SID
XDG_SESSION_PATH=/org/freedesktop/DisplayManager/Session0
UNITY_HAS_3D_SUPPORT=false
XDG_SEAT_PATH=/org/freedesktop/DisplayManager/Seat0
ORACLE_BASE=/u01/app/oracle
ORACLE_HOSTNAME=127.0.0.1
SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/run/user/1000/keyring/ssh
ftp_proxy=#######################
SESSION_MANAGER=local/huynq-VirtualBox:@/tmp/.ICE-unix/2277,unix/huynq-VirtualBox:/tmp/.ICE-unix/2277
DEFAULTS_PATH=/usr/share/gconf/ubuntu.default.path
GIO_LAUNCHED_DESKTOP_FILE=/usr/share/applications/terminator.desktop
UNITY_DEFAULT_PROFILE=unity-lowgfx
XDG_CONFIG_DIRS=/etc/xdg/xdg-ubuntu:/usr/share/upstart/xdg:/etc/xdg
MAIL=/var/mail/oracle
PATH=/u01/app/oracle/product/12.2.0/dbhome_1/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games
DESKTOP_SESSION=ubuntu
QT_QPA_PLATFORMTHEME=appmenu-qt5
QT_IM_MODULE=ibus
LC_IDENTIFICATION=vi_VN
JOB=unity-settings-daemon
PWD=/u01/app/oracle/product/12.2.0/dbhome_1/bin
XDG_SESSION_TYPE=x11
JAVA_HOME=/usr/bin/java
XMODIFIERS=@im=ibus
socks_proxy=#######################
SID=ORCL
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
GNOME_KEYRING_PID=
MANDATORY_PATH=/usr/share/gconf/ubuntu.mandatory.path
GDM_LANG=en_US
LC_MEASUREMENT=vi_VN
IM_CONFIG_PHASE=1
COMPIZ_CONFIG_PROFILE=ubuntu
GDMSESSION=ubuntu
https_proxy=#######################
GTK2_MODULES=overlay-scrollbar
SESSIONTYPE=gnome-session
XDG_SEAT=seat0
HOME=/home/oracle
SHLVL=2
LANGUAGE=en_US
GNOME_DESKTOP_SESSION_ID=this-is-deprecated
LIBGL_ALWAYS_SOFTWARE=1
UPSTART_INSTANCE=
TMP=/tmp
LOGNAME=oracle
XDG_SESSION_DESKTOP=ubuntu
UPSTART_EVENTS=xsession started
COMPIZ_BIN_PATH=/usr/bin/
CLASSPATH=/u01/app/oracle/product/12.2.0/dbhome_1/jlib:/u01/app/oracle/product/12.2.0/dbhome_1/rdbms/jlib
QT4_IM_MODULE=xim
XDG_DATA_DIRS=/usr/share/ubuntu:/usr/share/gnome:/usr/local/share:/usr/share:/var/lib/snapd/desktop:/var/lib/snapd/desktop
J2SDKDIR=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle
DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=unix:abstract=/tmp/dbus-5aFOIz1iEI
LESSOPEN=| /usr/bin/lesspipe %s
UPSTART_JOB=unity7
INSTANCE=
DISPLAY=:0
XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/1000
ORACLE_HOME=/u01/app/oracle/product/12.2.0/dbhome_1
XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=Unity
J2REDIR=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre
GTK_IM_MODULE=ibus
LC_TIME=vi_VN
LESSCLOSE=/usr/bin/lesspipe %s %s
COLORTERM=gnome-terminal
XAUTHORITY=/home/huynq/.Xauthority
LC_NAME=vi_VN
_=/usr/bin/env`
```

Answer (score 1):

> *There are two types of startup parameter files for Oracle Database
>   `pfile`(also called `init.ora` file which's of type `text` ) and
>   `spfile`( which's of type `binary` ). Prior to version `9i`, there was
>   only `pfile`, but still might be preferred but the preference is
>   mainly for backward compatibility with the older releases.*

If startup is performed with a pfile as in your case, you need to include the *file* and *path to file* :

`SQL> startup pfile=/u01/app/oracle/product/12.2.0/dbhome_1/dbs/initSID.ora`

or you can create a spfile firstly by

`SQL> create spfile from pfile='/u01/app/oracle/product/12.2.0/dbhome_1/dbs/initSID.ora'`

and then startup

`SQL> startup`

without specifying any file.

For enterprise manager, you need to check

`$ emctl status dbconsole` and see what it tells,

and check whether `ORACLE_SID` parameter is set.

Comment: Thank for the detail explain. But instead of that, I fix it by clone required **initSID.ora** file from **init.ora**. But it's fail when I access to https://127.0.0.1:5500/em. How to fix this?

Comment: emctl is not found and ORACLE_SID is SID

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need to set the environment variable ORACLE_SID to ORCL. Assuming you're in linux run this at the command line  '**env**', without the quotes, and update your original question with the output from that. When Oracle starts it looks for a number of environment variables, ORACLE_HOME and ORACLE_SID are 2 of the critical ones. By posting the output of the **env** command someone might be able to help.

Also, as a side note, I usually have better luck installing the Oracle database software first, and then creating a database using either the DBCA or the create database command. The latter is a little more advanced but is a good thing to learn.

Comment: Although I have tried to change ORACLE_SID to ORCL, but I still can not access to https://127.0.0.1:5500/em